There exists $x \in \mathbb R^3$ such that $Tx - 9x = (-4,5,\sqrt{7}).$
Here is the problem I am thinking about:
Suppose $T \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ and $-4,5,$ and $\sqrt{7}$ are eigenvalues of $T.$ Prove that there exists $x \in \mathbb R^3$ such that $Tx - 9x = (-4,5,\sqrt{7}).$
My question is:
I do not understand Understanding the statement of a problemwhat does it mean to show that there exists $x \in \mathbb R^3$ such that $Tx - 9x = (-4,5,\sqrt{7}).$ what does it mean to have an equality between a sum and an ordered triple?
Can someone explain this to me please?

$x \in \Bbb R^3$ and $Tx \in \Bbb R^3$. So, $Tx-9x$ is an element of $\Bbb R^3$.

I think the text of your homework is ill-posed.
It should be under the form
$$Tx-9x=V \tag{1}$$
where $V=(-4,5,\sqrt{7})^{\color{red}{T}]$ with the transpose operator in order that the given equality is between column vectors (not column vectors on one side and row vector on the other).
Now, how to solve the question ?
Recall : the eigenvalues $\lambda$ of a linear map $T$ are the "exceptional values" for which $T-\lambda I$ isn't invertible.
As $9$ isn't an eigenvalue of $T$, $T-9I$ is invertible which means that (1) can be written in an equivalent way under the form :
$$x=(T-9I)^{-1}V$$
giving a (unique !) solution $x$.

Who is the brave anonymous downvoter ?

It's not me, but just as a comment: you indeed solved the problem, but you didn't really answer his/her question, didn't you?

@Maik Pickl You are right. I didn't pay enough attention to the "real question" ; I have modified my answer.

This is Exercise 29 of Chapter 5A of this famous linear algebra textbook, and maybe you can send an email if you think it is ill-posed.

$T-9I$ invertible shouldn't be considered obvious at this level.

@non-euclidean geometry Rightful comment. I am going to give a complement.

Well yeah.   You might leave it as a nice little exercise,  but I wouldn't call it obvious.

@non-euclidean geometry This is a classical result that is met rather early in the linear algebra curriculum : see for example p. 135 of the Axler book referenced above by Seewoo Lee.
